# How to get reference to div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What am I doing wrong in the code below that I'm not able to get a reference to the *footer* div?

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>alert(document.getElementById('footer'));</script>
<div id="footer">testing footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: P.S. `<title></title>` should be inside head tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are calling `getElementById()` before the footer is loaded.

put the script at the bottom of the `body` or run in `onload`

Answer (score 0):

Place the script tag below the div you are trying to select.  I'm guessing the alert is returning null?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert(document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML);</script>
```

And put it after the DIV.

Note, the `innerHTML` is assuming you're just trying to get the text from within that div.

Comment: type="text/javascript" is not required anymore by modern browsers - it won't make a difference.

Comment: it was long ago: "This attribute is optional. Since Netscape 2, the default programming language in all browsers has been JavaScript. In HTML, it is better to leave it out. The browser knows what to do." http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="footer">testing footer</div>
<script>alert(document.getElementById('footer'));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *script* tag i located before the footer and thus  will be executed before the footer is created.

There are couple of things that you can do:

- place script below footer.
- add the `deferred` attribute to script
- attach to onload event